# Dynamic Pardot email link not getting tracked

Tags: email-template, pardot

I have created an email template in Pardot. Email template has a link/button which has dynamic URL by using Pardot Account Merge field & this merge field value is retrieved from Salesforce Account URL field type.

The HTML code of link looks like this:

```
<a href="{{Recipient.Account.URL_Value__c}}" style="color:#ffffff;">Click Here</a>
```

In above code, link works fine but link clicks are not tracked & I cannot use email click criteria in engagement studio program.

Also, when I read this [Salesforce Pardot help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_emails_link_tracking.htm&type=5), I tried to add explicit "https://" as prefix to URL and updated Account field to not to have "https://" stored in it.

```
<a href="https://{{Recipient.Account.URL_Value__c}}" style="color:#ffffff;">Click Here</a>
```

However, it also did not work & link in the email was broken.

I am not sure how can I create a link/button in Pardot email which has dynamic URL value from Pardot Merge field & link is tracked in engagement studio.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems to work on my org when i use engagement studio. Maybe you trouble is on your value {{Recipient.Account.URL_Value__c}}.

[image: demo template click]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178835)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found if you use triple brackets it works so https://{{{Recipient.Account.URL_Value__c}}}

No idea why but works for me!